# Is the python threading.ident the same as the Linux process id?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, multithreading

When I look at the process table (htop for example) I see many process id's for my python program. I am using the logging package to trace the output of the work done by my threads. However I am not sure that the thread id shown in the log is the same as the process id shown in htop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `threading.ident` property provides the thread identity, which is only used to distinguish between other threads or whether a thread has started.

If you want the process id of your application, you can use `os.getpid()` to get the PID of your current process. Alternatively, if you are using `subprocess` or `multiprocessing` to call your sub-processes, you can access their pids using `subprocess.Popen().pid` or `multiprocessing.Process().pid` respectively.

[subprocessing PID documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.pid)

[multiprocessing PID documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.pid)

Comment: how does this relate to the original question? Does this mean that Python thread at the OS level is a new process?